# How to define a concept which checks whether a class can have different type of template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

Using C++ type system and type arithmetic, I want to express the general concept of a [mathematical ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)). This is, to simplify, a set with zero, one, addition, multiplicatio and substraction. To keep it simple, I'll focus on just having an addition. Complete code can be found in my template library [aerobus](https://github.com/aerobus-open-source/aerobus)

First implementation is, for example, integers which I express this way :

```
struct I {
    template<int i>
    struct val {
        static constexpr int v = i;
    };

    template<typename v1, typename v2>
    using add_t = val<v2::v + v2::v>;
};
```

After that, I can define, for example, polynomial with coefficients in a general ring :

```
template<typename Ring>
struct polynomial {
    template<typename coeffN, typename... coeffs>
    struct val {
    };

    template<typename v1, typename v2>
    using add_t = (some implementation);
};
```

Since C++ introduced concepts, I'd like to express that Ring type parameter must be, indeed, a ring.

I wrote a simple version of a concept :

```
template <typename R>
concept IsRing = requires(R) {
    typename R::template val<0>;
    typename R::template add_t<typename R::template val<0>, typename R::template val<0>>;
};
```

which works well for my I struct.

However, it happens that polynomials are also a ring (in the math world)(I need it for expressing the [field of fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions) of an [integral domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain)) and

```
IsRing<polynomial<I>>
```

yields compile time failure :

> :30:19: error: static assertion failed    30 |    
> static_assert(IsRing>);
>       |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ :30:19: note: constraints not satisfied :2:9:   required by the constraints
> of 'template concept IsRing' :2:18:   in requirements
> with 'R ' [with R = polynomial] :3:14:
> note: the required type 'typename R::val' is invalid, because
>     3 |     typename R::template val;
>       |     ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ :3:14: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for
> 'template template struct polynomial::val'
> :3:14: note:   expected a type, got '0' :4:14: note:
> the required type 'typename R::add_t, typename
> R::val >' is invalid, because
>     4 |     typename R::template add_t, typename R::template val>;
>       |     ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> :4:14: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template
> parameter list for 'template
> template struct polynomial::val' :4:14: note:   expected a type, got '0'

which is fairly understandable since in polynomial, "values" have multiple type template parameters instead of a single integer constant.

How can I come with a concept general enough to express that polynomials (or other complex structures I can dream of) are indeed, rings ?

Comment: You can only check some exact usage. E.g. `typename T::val<42>;` is fine, but you can't check if it accepts any possible integer. Can you show the unfinished concept you have so far?

Comment: I don't really have something. Here some real val implementation : 

template<int32_t x>
  struct val {
   static constexpr int32_t v = x;

But it can also be : 

template<typename coeffN, typename... coeffs>
  struct val {};

Comment: But that looks like a completely different thing? They accept different kinds of template arguments.

Comment: Indeed. That's why the pain

Comment: Ok, but that just means two separate `requires{...}` expressions, with `||` in between. And again, you can't check "accepts 1+ template arguments" in general, only "accepts exactly N arguments of specific types".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I just did a major edit to further explain my problem

Comment: As written it's not possible. I would omit `val` from the concept altogether (since it's usage differs per ring, I don't see much sense in enforcing the name `val` in the first place). To test `add_t` you need to get the valid arguments somehow. Can't use `val` for that, but since you probably will have member typedefs for "zero" and "one", you can pass them to `add_t`. You can't really validate what `val_t` returns, unless you add a member "is value" concept to the ring type (or rather, since concepts can't be nested in classes, a `constexpr bool` template variable, a poor man's replacement).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements, I came up with the following concept:

```
template <typename R, auto X, typename V1, typename V2>
concept is_ring = requires(R)
{
    typename R::template val<X>;
    typename R::template add_t<V1, V2>;
};
```

---

##### Tests

For the given example:

```
struct V
{
    static const int value = 5;
};

struct R_right
{
    template <auto X>
    struct val {};

    template <typename V1, typename V2>
    using add_t = val<V1::value + V2::value>;
};

struct R_wrong
{

};

// Function to test the concept
template <auto X, typename V1, typename V2>
void test([[maybe_unused]] is_ring<X, V1, V2> auto r)
{

}
```

`R_right` is accepted while `R_wrong` is not:

```
int main()
{
    test<42, V, V>(R_right {});
    test<42, V, V>(R_wrong {}); // --> Error: constraints not satisfied

    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Live example here](https://godbolt.org/z/9hEM461r7)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks but as you will see with my edit, my actual problem is quite bigger. Sorry for the initial misexplanation

Comment: @RegisPortalez Oh I see, it's a different problem. Usually, when the question changes that radically, the guideline is to ask a new separate question (whether or not you delete this one) especially if you already have answers to the previous version of the question (which prevents them to be invalidated by the question's change).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I come with a concept general enough to express that
> polynomials (or other complex structures I can dream of) are indeed,
> rings ?

You can use template specialization to get the type of `R::val` to use as the template parameter for `R::add_t`

```
// helper class
template<class>
struct ring_val { };
template<class R>
  requires requires { typename R::template val<0>; }
struct ring_val<R> : std::type_identity<typename R::template val<0>> { };
template<class R>
  requires requires { typename R::template val<int>; }
struct ring_val<R> : std::type_identity<typename R::template val<int>> { };

template <typename R>
concept IsRing = requires {
  typename R::template add_t<typename ring_val<R>::type, 
                             typename ring_val<R>::type>;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KvdcnozEq)

Answer (score 0):

My two cents it to take a step back and define a ring in two pieces.  A ring is a set, and the set has over its elements some properties.

In your case, set means, any object that can be element of the ring, and from there, you want to decide if that set is a compile time constraint.  If not, then we can simply model a set as a collection, and from there we can come up with a C++ model for a ring.

To reference:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)

So, now, we can break down what our ring concept has to do as far as C++ goes.

It is a set, all of whose elements implement the operations per the requirements in Wiki, which means:

You want to the definition of the C++ set to an element.  We note that to add an item, or remove the item, C++ collections all have a similar semanatic.

You want to enforce first, there is a set, and you need a concept to enforce that, and then, you want to enforce that set, which does set things.

Well, there is a set in C++, but vectors are often more useful, so you perhaps want to decide as a concept that you can either pick a C++ collection and go with that, or, you can say, you have to implement some kind of an iterator, and you have to implement push_back or insert.

```
template <typename ring_set, typename ring_element> concept ring_set =
requires (ring_set ra, ring_element re) {
   ra.push_back(re);
   ra.begin();
   ra.end();
 }
```

As a start.  This is off the top of my code, so your mileage may vary.

Then, you have to define a concept that satisfies ring elements.

```
template <typename ring_element> concept ring_element =
requires (ring_element ra, ring_element rb, ring_element rc) {
   ra + rb == rc;
   ra - rb == rc;
 }
```

Other rules would need to be given, and the trick here, is that, there's one thing that I am not sure is so easily done with a template, and that is a need to establish communitivity.  See, the concept specification really asks, will this compile.  But it doesn't check if it is correct.